# WebGL: Display Depth Texture

Tags: webgl, framebuffer, depth

I'm new to WebGL and trying to implement depth textures for later usage in Shadow Maps.
Below is my code of the initilisation of the framebuffer. 
In the function drawTest I first bind all Buffers needed and draw the vertices of the Model into the framebuffer which is attached to a texture.
Shouldn't this work? All i got is a white screen and no error.

```
this.drawTest = function (model1) {

    this.model1 = model1;


        if (model1.Image.ReadyState === true && model1.Ready === false) {
            this.PrepareModel(model1);
        }
        if (model1.Ready) {
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.model1.Vertices);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.VertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model1.Triangles);
        }

        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.depthFramebuffer);

        gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, model1.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);




}


this.InitDrawDepth = function(size) {

        this.depthTextureExt = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_depth_texture"); // Or browser-appropriate prefix
        if(!this.depthTextureExt) { 
            console.log("WEBGL_depth_texture Extension not available!"); 
            return; 
        }

        // Create a color texture
        this.colorTexture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.colorTexture);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

        this.depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTexture);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, size, size, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);

       // var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
        this.depthFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.depthFramebuffer);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.colorTexture, 0);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTexture, 0);

        if(!gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            console.log("Framebuffer incomplete!");
        }

        //reset Framebuffer
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

        this.depthTextureSize = size;

    }
```

Comment: you mind jsFidlle-ing it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. I had another function causing trouble with the original buffers.
Thanks to everyone who tried to figure out the problem.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution? I am running into the same issue.